# Create PDF from (La)TeX

Tags: c++, pdf, latex, pdf-generation

Is there any C/C++ **programming library** which could help me generate PDF file from (La)TeX? If there is no such thing, is there any other way I could generate PDF from (La)TeX?

Comment: There is no library, only pdfTeX, luaTeX and XeTeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pdflatex (should be part of every recent LaTeX distribution)

Comment: isn't pdfLaTex computer program? I'm seeking for programming library which I could use as a part of my program, not for whole program with GUI and stuff.

Comment: to use LaTeX, you will need a lot of "stuff" like style or font files.  The 'pdflatex' program is -- compared to these data -- very small and you won't gain very much by using a library.  By calling it with `-interaction batchmode -halt-on-error` options (available in pdflatex of texlive distribution), you can detect and handle errors.

Comment: It is important because on an iOS app you can't run another executeable. And having a wrapper around the file loader so that all files could be included in the binary would be nice too

Answer (score 2):

pdflatex.

Also (kinda workaround) installing [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org), you can open/import latex and export pdf/rtf/whatever.